# How to exclude the _id field while retrieving and displaying data from MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

How do i exclude the _id field from the set of fields returned in C#, there are posts on this website that mention of the .include() and .exclude() methods but those methods are not present in my case.

below is the code where 'secondary' is a field in the outer document which is an array and '.amount' is the field nested within the 'secondary' array ( like a nested document ). Can someone help me out with this please..!

```
 var fields = "secondary.amount";
        foreach (var document in collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().SetFields(fields))
        {
            foreach (string name in document.Names)
            {
                BsonElement element = document.GetElement(name);                  
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", element.Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Include` and `Exclude` methods are available, they're just not easy to find because they're off in a separate `Fields` builder class:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders; // Make Fields class accessible

var fields = "secondary.amount";
foreach (var document in collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>()
    .SetFields(Fields.Include(fields).Exclude("_id"))
{
    foreach (string name in document.Names)
    {
        BsonElement element = document.GetElement(name);                  
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", element.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says .. the name 'Fields' does not exist in the correct context.. !! can you please help me on this.. !

Comment: @Neville Be sure to add a `using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;`.

Comment: could you please help me out with this question also which i have posted an hour ago, thanks once again, really appreciate your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998239/how-to-retrieve-values-from-an-array-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp