# How to retrieve values from an array in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

Below in the code that retrieves the elements in the form of a BsonArray. I just want to fetch the numeric value from the array and use that value to calculate the sum.

```
var fields = "secondary.amount";
    foreach (var document in collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().SetFields(fields))
    {
        foreach (string name in document.Names)
        {
            BsonElement element = document.GetElement(name);                  
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", element.Value);
        }
    }
```

I tried converting the bson element to an int64, int32, double and then use the numeric value for addition but i get a runtime error of not able to cast a bsonarray etc. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: are you make mistake and paste code from another questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995286/how-to-exclude-the-id-field-while-retrieving-and-displaying-data-from-mongodb-u ? :)

Comment: if you have bsonarray then convert it to Array, not to simple types as int and double

Comment: @razon, that another question is also mine but that question is different and this one is a continuation.. , so this BsonElement which you are seeing in the code above is actually a BsonArray

Comment: What does your document look like in the server? And, as @razon said, if it's a BsonArray, then convert it to a BsonArray first...

Comment: @CraigWilson - i answered it as i figured out the solution, it works now.. !! Many thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, by making the following changes and it works now:

```
foreach (BsonDocument nestedDocument in Document["name"].AsBsonArray)
                        {
                            Total += Convert.ToDouble(nestedDocument["amount"]);
                        }
```